# How to move icons to the inventory bar in Minecraft for android?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My grandson can play Minecraft on a friend's iPad. On his android phone, he can't move items to the inventory bar.

He has tried:

- dragging and dropping with finger
- tapping on the icon then tapping the inventory

Comment: OK. I cracked it using Ctrl-Alt-Del. Delete the app. Redownload. Sorry for wasting people's time. For info, he taps the icon, then taps the inventory.